Understanding Equivalence of Matrix Elements in Different Bases for Hermitian Operators
Suppose $Q$ and $R$ are two system (which are represented by state vectors in the vector space V) on the same vector space $V$

$|i\rangle$ is an ortonormal base of $V$
$|i_R\rangle$ is an ortonormal base of $R$
$|i_Q\rangle$ is an ortonormal base of $Q$
$A$ is an hermitian operator on $R$
$B$ is an hermitian operator on $Q$

Now I write an element of A respect the base $|i_R\rangle$  like $\langle i_R|A|j_R\rangle = A_{i_Rj_R}$. So for the others basis is the same
Now I've see that $\sum_{ij}A_{i_Rj_R}B_{i_Qj_Q} = \sum_{ij}A_{ij}B_{ij}$ but I can't understend why they are equals, how can trasform two differente index $i_R$ and $i_Q$ in the same $i$? Or my equivalence is wrong?

"Now I've seen that ...". Where? How? Where does that equation come from? Under which assumptions?

It was a passage that I found in a demostration of the Hilbert-Schmidt product, so i reported only this part with all the assumptions that make the book
